# Using mouseover and mouseout in jQuery, not giving expected output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 div elements i am opening 2nd div element on 1st div element's mouseover even and closing it on mouseout. code as follow.

```js
jQuery('.something').on('mouseover', function() {
  jQuery(jQuery(this).next('div')).slideDown();
})

jQuery('.something').on('mouseout', function() {
  jQuery(jQuery(this).next('div')).slideUp();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something" style="background:red; height:200px; width:200px">
</div>
<div class="something1" style="background:#000; height:200px; width:200px; position:absolute; top: 0; display: none;">
</div>
```

The problem is when hovering over element if the cursor is moved even a little bit, it executes mouseover and mouseout events.

[Here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandeeppujare/gxm4z2Lz/)

Comment: And also, it is recommended to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none;`

```
.something1 {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: @SandeepPujare remember to mark as accepted if you accept the answer so others can know it's a good answer;

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of `mouseover` event, if you interact using mouse it will keep on handling the same event.

That's why [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```js
jQuery('.something').on('mouseover', function() {
  jQuery(jQuery(this).next('div')).slideDown();
})

jQuery('.something').on('mouseout', function() {
  jQuery(jQuery(this).next('div')).slideUp();
})
```

```css
.something1 {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something" style="background:red; height:200px; width:200px">
</div>
<div class="something1" style="background:#000; height:200px; width:200px; position:absolute; top: 0; display: none;">
</div>
```